# Definition of continuity of open balls or delta

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functions, continuity

I know how to prove the theorem of the following:

**A function f is continuous if and only if the preimage of any open set in Y is open in X.**

I am wondering how to show that the theorem is equivalent to the two different definitions of continuity of i) open balls and ii) delta epsilon.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you having trouble showing that Definition A implies Definition B, or that Definition B implies Definition A?

Comment: Why is that a theorem?  It's a definition.  No, they are not completely equivalent.  The open set definition is used for all topological spaces.  The balls  version holds only for metric spaces while that old fashion epsilon-delta thing hold only for normed spaces,